# "concurrently" not working for parent directory client reactjs server

Tags: reactjs, concurrently

"concurrently" not working for parent directory client reactjs server.

concurrently commands are:

```
"scripts": {
    "client": "cd ../ --prefix client && npm run start",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev" : "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\" "
  }
```

Directory structure is

client
server

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

With Your folder structure Try this settings:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "server": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  },
```

And hit `npm run dev` It should work fine ;-) Remember to install [concurrently](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently) correct.